# Using a jQuery plugin in a Rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to set up a very basic lightbox effect for a login in a Rails application. I'm using a the plugin Lightbox Evolution. Usage is as follows per the directions:

- Make sure it is a valid DOCTYPE.
- Include the jQuery library lightbox CSS and the lightbox js file in the head of the pages where you want to use the lightbox
- Initialize the plugin:

  `<script type="text/javascript"
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('.lightbox').lightbox();
  });
  </script>`

The jquery.lightbox.min.js and jquery.lightbox.css are located in the vendor/assets/javascripts and vendor/assets/stylesheets directories respectively.

I've included the lightbox script in the application.html.erb file since I plan on using the lightbox effect on other places on the site.

My application.html.erb file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test App</title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "jquery.lightbox.css", :media => "all" %>   
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.lightbox.min" %>   
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
   <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
   <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
   <%= yield %>

   <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.lightbox').lightbox();
  });
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

My landing page is app/views/welcome/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Landing Page</h1>
<a href="users/sign_in" class="lightbox">Login</a>
```

and I use the class "lightbox" per the instructions.

When I go to localhost:3000, the html is built as follows in development environment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>MetaLinx Material Management</title>
   <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/containers.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/scales.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/welcome.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="/assets/jquery.lightbox.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
   <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/containers.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.mouse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.sortable.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.position.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.menu.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/jquery.ui.timepicker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/ra.datetimepicker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/jquery.colorpicker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/ra.filter-box.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/ra.filtering-multiselect.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/ra.filtering-select.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/ra.remote-form.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/jquery.pjax.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_nested_form.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/ra.nested-form-hooks.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/ra.widgets.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/custom/ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails_admin/rails_admin.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/scales.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/welcome.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.lightbox.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
 <meta content="NGWSCp8qKAwi52ViQNfSP+2WG4teWxwOzCDCFfqQaLc=" name="csrf-token" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <p class="notice"></p>
   <p class="alert"></p>
   <h1>Landing Page</h1>
 <p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>

<a href="users/sign_in" class="lightbox">Login</a>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('.lightbox').lightbox();
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

I'm using devise for authentication, so it sets up the routes for users/sign_in. When I click the link above, it takes me to the page users/new, but it does not pop-up in the lightbox. the generated html looks like:

app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

So the question is what am I doing wrong so that when I click the "Login" link in app/views/welcome/new.html.erb it take me to the login page rather than popping it up using the lightbox jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try change `href="users/sign_in"` to `href="#"`. Since the link really doesn't matter if you just wanna click on it and let lightbox pops out the login form.